# Upper and Lower Bounds for Confidence Intervals on a one tail hypothesis test.

Tags: statistics, education, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

CI(99) = xbar ± Zcv( σ / √ n -1 )

My question is if the test is a one tail hypothesis test, do I still do two separate equations + and -.

Here is the formula filled in (if it is the correct formula) CI(99) = xbar ± (-2.33? or |2.33|)(.56 / √86-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a one-sided confidence interval, then you need to adjust your Z-score such that the probability above that Z-score (for upper-tail tests, lower CI) or below that Z-score (for lower-tail tests, upper CI) is equal to your significance level.

For example, a 1-sided, lower confidence interval is: $-\infty $ to $\bar x + z_{1-\alpha}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$, while the upper confidence interval is $\bar x - z_{1-\alpha}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ to $\infty$

BTW: If you're using a z-test, then you are assuming you know the variance, and hence you don't need to divide by n-1, just n. The n-1 is only used in estimating an unbiased sample variance - note: the square root of the unbiased varince estimator is not unbiased, but biased low...the correction for this is tedious and often unnecessary if your sample size is greater than a handful of points.

Comment: n-1 is part of the z test equation. I asked my prof why, his response "Excellent question.  The n-1 refers to a mathematical correction that accounts for expected differences in variance between the sample and the population.  Because we are using the sample SD in our equation, we make the adjustment.  This week you will be learning about degrees of freedom, which will shed more light on this issue.  Also, as you are probably picking up by now, there are indeed some variations and nuances in approaches to the same statistical results (just as there are variations in notation)..."

Comment: I couldn't find anyone else doing it this way however for z tests.

Comment: @TYPKRFT your professor is correct that there are varations in some statisticial analyses...however, this is *not* one of them. The theory of the normal distribution is very well undersood. You have two choices if you assume that your population is normally distributed: either assume you know the variance and use a Z-test, or estimate the variance and use the T-test.

Comment: @TYPKRFT (cont'd) It is not correct to say that dividing by n-1 corrects the bias in the sample *standard deviation*...it only applies to the *sample variance*. When you take the square root of the unbiased sample variance estimator, you end up with a *biased* estimate of the standard deviation. If your professor disagrees, ask him to explain Jensen's inequality to you...it states that the expected value of a concave function  of a random varialbe will be *less* than a concave function of the expected value of the variable. I.e., $E[\sqrt{\hat s^2}]\leq \sqrt{E[\hat s^2]} = \sigma$

Comment: Again I am not sure. Why he said that...I mean he is teaching at one of the best universities in America...He must have some reason or I failed to pick something up that I didnt explain correctly. But I am not saying your wrong